# Adding two unicode chars in java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stuck in my program that emulates a 8bit processor. I have an array of characters in Unicode(hex) that I call memory. I'm trying to pass my operand of type int a two byte word which will be two unicode values in my array. Lets say myArray[1] has '\u00BF' and myArray[2] has '\u00FF' so I want to pass '\uBFFF' to my operand. I was thinking of parsing the char to its bytes value into a string, concatenating the  two, and then passing it to an int. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "pass my operand of type int a two byte word"? Also, just fyi, a unicode character is 2 bytes wide,

Comment: Unlike in C, you should never use a Java char to represent a byte value.  In your case, you probably want to use a [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) instead of a naked array, as ByteBuffer has methods like [getShort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#getShort-int-) that will do exactly what you want.  Also pay attention to the [ByteBuffer.order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-) method.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the type of array. I'm sorry I'm horrible at explaining but I basically want to add two Unicode characters but get the concatenation as a result. Such as '\u0012' + '\u0034' will get me '\u1234'. I will then get the int result of '\u1234' which is 4660.

Comment: I figured out a way of parsing from Unicode to hex, then from hex to String, concatenating and then from hex to decimal but I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing it that I can't see.

Comment: In other words this is what I currently have:

int word = Integer.parseInt(Integer.toHexString(EA) + Integer.toHexString(EA + 1), 16);

where EA is an int value of a location in the array so I'm getting two side by side location in my array and getting their concatenated result.